# tvOS - Video Looping Stutter

Tags: swift, swiftui, tvos

I am using the `AVPlayerLooper` to loop an MP4 but also tried as an MOV. This is a single track video with no audio tracks. I have also tried other looping videos sourced from differing places, with the same result. That result is at video's end, there is a brief stutter as the video restarts. It does this from the first thorough the nth iteration. All files are included in the app's bundle so no network forces are in play. Trying to understand the cause of these stutters and what may be put into place to resolve them.

```
struct VideoLooperView: View {
    var videoName:String

    var body: some View {
        VideoLooperRep(videoName: videoName)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct VideoLooperRep:UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var videoName:String

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some VideoVC {
        let vc = VideoVC(videoName: videoName)
        return vc
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {}
}

class VideoVC:AVPlayerViewController {
    private var queuePlayer:AVQueuePlayer!
    private var videoLooper:AVPlayerLooper!
    private var videoName:String!
    
    init(videoName:String) {
        self.videoName = videoName
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        playVideo()
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = false
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        queuePlayer?.pause()
    }
    
    private func playVideo() {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: ".mov")!
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)
        let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
        self.queuePlayer = AVQueuePlayer(playerItem: item)
        self.videoLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: self.queuePlayer, templateItem: item)
        self.player = self.queuePlayer
        self.queuePlayer.play()
    }
}
```